# Gnuplot - incremented minutes to days

Tags: time, gnuplot, axis

I have data CNV file, where the first column is "minutes from start."

```
Minutes;Temperature
0;15.5
60;15.8
120;15.6
180;16.1
....
```

I would like to plot this data with x-axis as time (DAYS), so that every 1440 minutes is 1 day, then comes day 2... etc. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply divide the minutes by 60 and by 24 (or 1440). Then you will have days.
Note, column values, e.g. `$1`, are always taken as float, so you don't have to worry about gnuplot's integer division (which can lead to unexpected results if you don't know about it).

```
plot "YourFile.dat" u ($1/1440):2 with lines
```